# 403 Error while testing gitlab API in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, continuous-integration

I am building a CICD using Jenkins and Gitlab on-premise, first I added the GitLab API in Jenkins and testes the connection and it **succeded**,
but when I try to run the job I get 403 error, The repo is public and doesn't have any protected branches, but jenkins can't fetch the repo..

I tried to delete the API  and do another access token, but this time the connection test fails and give me a 403 error again.

***now I have two 403 errors when I make an API and fetching a branch***.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiZY0.png)

***UPDATE*** problem is solved. I was using a proxy and it was causing the error. it connects now and no 403 errors are showing.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried, Jenkinsfile or script where you have used the API ?

Comment: @SouravAtta I added a pic for the error... i have not used it in Jenkinsfile I check the git as a source and added my url with the creds.